# What's the reason of curvature in Tanabe-Sugano diagrams?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, spectroscopy, transition-metals, crystal-field-theory

Analysing Tanabe-Sugano diagrams it's evident that some of the lines are pretty parallels to that of the ground field whilst others are inclinated or have some curvature.

I know what's the effect on the line width of the spectra, but I'd like to have an explanation on why we have so different behaviours.

The fact that in Orgel diagrams some lines are straight and others have curvature is related to this?

Comment: For readers:  [Wikipedia: Tanabe-Sugano diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tanabe%E2%80%93Sugano_diagram) and [Orgel diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orgel_diagram) // See also Libretexts   [here](https://chem.libretexts.org/Ancillary_Materials/Reference/Reference_Tables/Spectroscopic_Reference_Tables/Tanabe-Sugano_Diagrams) and [here](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Inorganic_Chemistry/Supplemental_Modules_and_Websites_(Inorganic_Chemistry)/Crystal_Field_Theory/Orgel_Diagrams)